# Returning reference of a local variable from a friend function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, pass-by-reference, friend, local-variables

I came across an example for overloading the << and >> operators in C++. However, got a doubt as all the examples that implement it seem to be returning reference to a local variable

```
class Date  
{  
    int mo, da, yr;  
public:  
    Date(int m, int d, int y)  
    {  
        mo = m; da = d; yr = y;  
    }  
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& dt);  
};  

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& dt)  
{  
    os << dt.mo << '/' << dt.da << '/' << dt.yr;  
    return os;  
}  

int main()  
{  
    Date dt(5, 6, 92);  
    cout << dt;  
}
```

I think os is a local variable (correct me if it is not, somehow).

I don't know if this code really works but in most of the references on the web, I found similar implementations.

Note: inclusion of header files and using namespace std statements are omitted on purpose.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a reference, not a local variable

Comment: `os` is a local variable but the object it references is not a local variable.

Comment: 1. it isn't a local variable. 2. friend has nothing to do with it.

Comment: What does it mean to return by reference, then?

Comment: Think of it as just passing and returning the name of some object. You get an object named "Bob", and the caller of the function expects a name as well, so you just pass "Bob" as the name.

Comment: This is not a forum. Don't broaden a question endlessly with information from answers. It invalidates them, and is quite rude. If you have another question, post it after searching that it wasn't asked before.

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: Hint: Your constructor should use an initialisation list, not assignments, and you don't have to invent different parameter names: `Date(int mo, int da, int yr) : mo(mo), da(da), yr(yr) {}`

Answer (score 3):

> I think os is a local variable (correct me if it is not, somehow).

It's not really. `os` is a local reference, that's true. But it's bound to a non-local object.

And since it's a non-const lvalue reference it must be bound to an object whose lifetime exceeds the function call. So binding that reference to the one that is returned from the function is perfectly okay. Nothing will end up dangling.

In fact, that's what you must do to enable chained calling of functions:

```
std::cout << foo << bar << baz;
```

Is just a bunch of function calls:

```
operator<<(operator<<(operator<<(std::cout, foo), bar), baz);
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. :)

Comment: @KrishnaKumar Please have a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) topic.

Comment: This is not 100% true. It can be dangling if the parameter which was passed into the function is rvalue. e.g `std::ostream& wrong = std::operator<< (std::stringstream(), "Hello World");`

Comment: @OriBS - It can be an rvalue only on MSVC. And MSVC sucks for this very reason.

Comment: Meant for the general case. And wasn't aware it is not this way with other compilers. Nice to know it!

Comment: @OriBS - The general case is immaterial. The question (and as my answer explicitly notes) is about a non-const lvalue ref. If it was a const lvalue ref it would be a totally different dance.

Comment: @StoryTeller: MSVC will produce a diagnostic message for that case if used with `/W4`, and even an error if used with `/permissive-` in newer versions.